# Powershell WMI Query failing when executed from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, permissions, wmi, scheduled-tasks

i have a strange problem...

i have the following code, which takes the output from Sysinternals Disk Usage tool (link below)
[Disk Usage - Sys Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651)

so first i get the physical drives into array $Disks, then i enumerate these through the foreach and mess about with them.

my problem lies in this line *$Dir =  du.exe -q -v $d.DeviceID*

```
$PC = get-content env:COMPUTERNAME
$Disk = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype=3"

    foreach ($d in $Disk)
    {
    $Dir =  du.exe -q -v $d.DeviceID
    $Dir[8..($Dir.length-8)] | foreach {
    $Size = $_.substring(0,10).replace(",","")/1024
    $Path = $_.substring(10)
    }
}
```

$d.DeviceID should be the drive letter (i.e. C:)

then i populate $Dir with the output from DU.exe, but $d.DeviceID is not acting how it is supposed to, running this from a task has this following result   (added a line that says $d.DeviceID, to show the output):

B:
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\DU.ps1:25 char:6
+ $Dir[ <<<< 8..($Dir.length-8)] | foreach {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [],
    RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

C:
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\DU.ps1:25 char:6
+ $Dir[ <<<< 8..($Dir.length-8)] | foreach {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [],
    RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

D:
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\DU.ps1:25 char:6
+ $Dir[ <<<< 8..($Dir.length-8)] | foreach {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [],
    RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

running it from the ISE or just from the Shell has no issues, running it on other servers from all methods works.

i do believe the population of the $Dir vairable is the problem, as the du.exe has trouble with the $d.DeviceID

i dont understand why it is just this server/task sheduler that has the issue. i have tried the following:

redefined the array element to $i = $d.deviceID to fix it down - nothing
exported the job from other server (both DCs) an imported - nothing
restarted the winmgmt service - nothing

i think its a permissions issue, but im running this on an AD as THE Dom Admin with top privilages.

please can you guys help on this one, really am stuck...

cheers

Lee

Answer (score 1):

Yet another update based on comment below:

Try:

```
$cmd = "du.exe `-q `-v $($d.DeviceID)"
$dir = Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

Updating as per the comment below.

Take this example. This can get the size of every folder and display size and full path to the folder.

```
Function Get-FolderSize {
    Param ($folderPath)
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $folderPath -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    return $colItems.sum/1MB
}

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Scripts
$folders | % {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
        $size = Get-FolderSize $_.FullName
        Write-Host $size
        Write-Host $_.FullName
    }
}
```

You can use WMI to get the drive letter and pass it to the script. For example:

```
$disks = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype=3"
$disks | % {
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.DeviceID -Force
    $items | % {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            $size = Get-FolderSize $_.FullName
            Write-Host $size
            Write-Host $_.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

So, with this, you dont need DU.exe. You can run this as a script.

--------------OLD ANSWER _-------------------

First thing I would suspect is the path to DU.exe. What is the working directory set on the scheduled task? Is it the place where DU.exe is available?

BTW, what is the goal of this script? Are you just looking at the disk drive size? What are you capturing into $path? I did not have the patience to test your code. But, I feel that this can be easily achieved using just WMI and no other external tools.

Comment: Hi ravikanth, du.exe is located @ C:\windows\system32 so its always found, saying that i have changed the code to ref the whole path. it would give me a not a recognised program/path error also. there is no working directory set, although i think that will be the system32 folder as its Powershell.  the goal of the script is to take every folder path under all the drive, and inject that into a SQL table so we can moniter folder size at a low level.  this is about directory size not Disk space.  $Path is the part of the line from the file that is the directory path.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check if that helps

Comment: sorry need to be more specific, i think its to do with powershell interpriting $d.deviceID as the output to the screen is good, but its not passing it to du.exe properly to fill

Comment: Hmm. I don't know how to add code in the comments box. Updated my answer again!

Comment: `Cannot index into a null array. At C:\du.ps1:31 char:10 + $Dir[ <<<< 8..($Dir.length-8)] | foreach { + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: is in response to your latest bit of code... your use of gci does work, but im starting to think about the diferences between the execution methods and why this server is handling the code a different way to all the other servers this runs on.

Comment: You may also need to prefix du.exe with .\  and I never ran your code. So, I am not sure why DU.exe in a scheduled task is not working.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it does solve the issue of making the script work, but having a work around to solve this issue, i fell is only delaying an issue that i have with htis server an the way it executes scripts...